# Unable to growpart because no space left

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I'm running an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance with EBS storage initially of 8GB.

This is now 99.8% full, so I've followed AWS documentation instructions to increase the EBS volume to 16GB. I now need to extend my partition /dev/xvda1 to 16GB, but when I run the command

```
$ growpart /dev/xvda 1
```

I get the error

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/tmp/growpart.2626’: No space left on device
```

I have tried

1. rebooting the instance
2. stopping the instance, and mounting a newly created EBS volume of size 16GB based on a snapshot of the old 8GB volume
3. running `docker system prune -a` (resulting in a "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:/var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?" error. When I try to start the daemon using `sudo dockerd`, I get a "no space left on device" error as well)
4. running `resize2fs /dev/xvda1`

all to no avail.

Running `lsblk` returns

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0    0   89M  1 loop /snap/core/7713
loop1     7:1    0   18M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1480
loop2     7:2    0 89.1M  1 loop /snap/core/7917
loop3     7:3    0   18M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1455
xvda    202:0    0   16G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0    8G  0 part /
```

`df -h` returns

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           395M   16M  379M   4% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.7G  7.7G     0 100% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/7713
/dev/loop1       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1480
/dev/loop2       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/7917
/dev/loop3       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1455
tmpfs           395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/1000
```

and `df -i` returns

```
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            501743    296 501447    1% /dev
tmpfs           504775    457 504318    1% /run
/dev/xvda1     1024000 421259 602741   42% /
tmpfs           504775      1 504774    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           504775      3 504772    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           504775     18 504757    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       12827  12827      0  100% /snap/core/7713
/dev/loop1          15     15      0  100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1480
/dev/loop2       12829  12829      0  100% /snap/core/7917
/dev/loop3          15     15      0  100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1455
tmpfs           504775     10 504765    1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Did you try it as a root user? After getting this error I used `sudo su` and follow this process https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html

Answer (score 231, accepted):

For anyone that has this problem, here's a link to the answer: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ebs-volume-size-increase/

Summary

1. Run `df -h` to verify your root partition is full (100%)
2. Run `lsblk` and then `lsblk -f` to get block device details
3. `sudo mount -o size=10M,rw,nodev,nosuid -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp`
4. `sudo growpart /dev/DEVICE_ID PARTITION_NUMBER`
5. `lsblk` to verify partition has expanded
6. `sudo resize2fs /dev/DEVICE_IDPARTITION_NUMBER`
7. Run `df -h` to verify your resized disk
8. `sudo umount /tmp`

Comment: in my case step#3 was the key `sudo mount -o size=10M,rw,nodev,nosuid -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp` and in case of step#6 didn't worked at all, i had to reboot the instance itself to make it work.

Comment: How do you find out DEVICE_ID and PARTITION_NUMBER? My device is `nvme0n1p2` so I just guessed it to be `nvme0n1` and `2` respectively, and it seemed to work. But now I can't get the `resize2fs` command to work with those values.

Comment: Edit: the reason I can't use `resize2f` is because it isn't installed, and I don't have storage space to install it.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I had to run `sudo apt-get autoclean` and `sudo apt-get autoremove` to get a little space and then I could run step 3. After step 8, I had to reboot `sudo reboot`.

Comment: Getting Temporary failure in name resolution at #3

Comment: I wish I could save this comment in my profile somehow.

Comment: This worked for me! But I had to run `sudo xfs_growfs -d /` in step 6 since my file system is XFS-type

Comment: What does `3` do ? Isn't `/tmp` already mounted under `tmpfs` ?

Comment: can someone explain how this works ? why mounting tmpfs suddenly makes growpart command successful ? earlier what internal operation was not allowing growpart to succeed but mounting of tmpfs makes it successful ?

Answer (score 14):

Just make sure to clear `tmp` folders before running the command `growpart /dev/xvda 1` by running this other command `sudo mount -o size=10M,rw,nodev,nosuid -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp` that should do the trick.

Here is the full recap on resizing EBS volume:

Run `df -h` to verify your disk is full (100%)

`/dev/xvda1      8.0G  8.0G   20K 100% /`

Run `lsblk`

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  20G  0 disk
`-xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
```

Clear `tmp` folders a little bit

`sudo mount -o size=10M,rw,nodev,nosuid -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp`

And finally increase space in the partition

`sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1`

```
CHANGED: partition=1 start=4096 old: size=16773087 end=16777183 new: size=41938911 end=41943007
```

And finally do a `sudo reboot` wait for the instance to fully reload, ssh into the instance and run `df -h` should show the new space added:

```
/dev/xvda1       20G  8.1G   12G  41% /
```

Notice the new available space, and see how it's not full anymore (not at `100%` now it's at `41%`)

Comment: can you explain how this works ? why mounting tmpfs suddenly makes growpart command successful ? earlier what internal operation was not allowing growpart to succeed but mounting of tmpfs makes it successful ?

Answer (score 4):

I came across this article http://www.daniloaz.com/en/partitioning-and-resizing-the-ebs-root-volume-of-an-aws-ec2-instance/ and solved it with ideas from there.

Steps taken:

1. Note down root device (e.g. /dev/sda1)
2. Stop instance
3. Detach root EBS volume and then modify volume size if you haven't already
4. Create an auxiliary instance (e.g. a `t2.micro` instance, or use an existing one if you wish)
5. Attach the volume from step 2 to the auxiliary instance (doesn't matter which device)
6. In the auxiliary instance, run `lsblk` to ensure the volume has been mounted correctly
7. `sudo growpart /dev/xvdf 1` (or similar, to expand the partition)
8. `lsblk` to check that the partition has grown
9. Detach the volume
10. Attach the volume to your original instance, with device set to the one you noted down in Step 1
11. Start the instance and then SSH into it
12. If you still get the message "Usage of /:   99.8% of X.XX GB", run `df -h` to check the size of your root volume partition (e.g. `/dev/xvda1`)
13. Run `sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1` (or similar) to resize your partition
14. Run `df -h` to check that your `Use%` of `/dev/xvda1` is no longer ~100%

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I delete cache and unnecessary files.

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

After that, I follow this blog:

https://devopsmyway.com/how-to-extend-aws-ebs-volume-with-zero-downtime/

Comment: ❯ apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: IO Error saving source cache
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: You can't `sudo apt-get autoclean` because no space left. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, however, my mongo was in a AWS EC2 instante running a CentOS 7, so I had to take a few different steps. For those like me reading this, try to follow:

1. Increase the EBS Volume using the AWS Panel;
2. Extend the file system of NVMe EBS volume using this tutorial from AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html;
3. As your database hit 100%, so maybe is necessary to use this command before to create a temporary folder for logs: `sudo mount -o size=10M,rw,nodev,nosuid -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp`;
4. Remove the `mongod.lock`. To find this file, look for the `dbPath` inside the `/etc/mongod.conf`;
5. Repair the database using this: `sudo mongod --repair /dbPath/from/mongodconf`. Depending on the database size, this repair might take some hours to complete. Mine took 3 hours.
6. `sudo chown -R mongod:mongod /dbPath/from/mongoconf` to make mongod own the folder again;
7. Restart mongo: `sudo service mongod restart`;
8. After that, your database might connect again;

Hope it helps.