# Unable to resize EC2 EBS partition - cannot extend

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, storage, partitioning, volume

I was running low and the volume was showing 100% used space. It was 40GB in size volume.

I increased the volume size from 40GB to 50GB from the AWS Console.

But then to extend it, I ran some commands as given in the `[instructions page of AWS][1]` but unfortunately got no space left to extend the partition, then I found another [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63071486/4728323) to resolve my issue, but maybe I chose the wrong partition # and got into a problem.

Now I don't know what to do next to fix the issue. The volume size in the AWS appears 50GB. But in the server, the volume size is still showing 40GB.

**History of commands I ran**

```
  233  df -hT
  234  lsblk
  235  sudo growpart /dev/nvme0n1p1 1
  236  df -h
  237  lsblk
  238  lsblk -f
  239  sudo mount -o size=10M,rw,nodev,nosuid -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp
  240  sudo growpart /dev/nvme0n1p1 1
  241  sudo growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1
  242  df -h
  243  lsblk
  244  sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1 1
  245  sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1p1 1
  246  df -h
  247  lsblk
  248  sudo growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1
  249  sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1 1
  250  df -h
  251  lsblk
  252  df -hT
  253  lsblk
  254  sudo growpart nvme0n1 1
  255  lsblk
  256  lslbk
  257  lsblk
  258  df -hT
  259  lsblk
  260  lsblk -f
  261  sudo growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1
  262  sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1
  263  lsblk
  264  df -hT
  265  sudo umount /tmp
  266  df -hT
  267  sudo growpart /dev/nvme01 1
  268  sudo growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1
  269  history
  270  df -hT
  271  lsblk
  272  sudo growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1
  273  sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1
  274  history
```

**Output of df -hT**

```
ubuntu@ip-192-168-00-00:~$ df -hT
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root      ext4       39G   36G  2.9G  93% /
devtmpfs       devtmpfs  7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G  1.1M  1.6G   1% /run
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop2     squashfs   27M   27M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/5163
/dev/loop10    squashfs   68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/22526
/dev/loop9     squashfs   56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2344
/dev/loop3     squashfs   68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/22753
/dev/loop11    squashfs   56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2409
/dev/loop8     squashfs   26M   26M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/5656
/dev/loop12    squashfs   62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1494
/dev/loop5     squashfs   62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1518
/dev/loop0     squashfs   47M   47M     0 100% /snap/snapd/16010
/dev/loop6     squashfs   47M   47M     0 100% /snap/snapd/16292
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

**Output of lsblk:**

```
ubuntu@ip-192-168-192-236:~$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0   47M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16010
loop2         7:2    0 26.7M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/5163
loop3         7:3    0 67.8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22753
loop4         7:4    0 61.9M  1 loop
loop5         7:5    0 61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1518
loop6         7:6    0   47M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16292
loop7         7:7    0 43.6M  1 loop
loop8         7:8    0 25.1M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/5656
loop9         7:9    0 55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2344
loop10        7:10   0 67.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22526
loop11        7:11   0 55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2409
loop12        7:12   0 61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1494
nvme0n1     259:0    0   50G  0 disk
└─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   50G  0 part /
```

**Output of growpart:**

```
ubuntu@ip-192-168-192-236:~$ sudo growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1
NOCHANGE: partition 1 is size 104855519. it cannot be grown
```

**Output of resize2fs:**

```
ubuntu@ip-192-168-192-236:~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/nvme0n1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

[image: aws console showing volume size]

Comment: Is this the boot drive of an Amazon Linux instance? If so, just reboot the instance and the OS will automatically expand to use the space available.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Rebooting the server worked and now I got all the space that I was looking for.
Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem of online resizing. The problem belong to the different name of AWS Admin Panel Device Name /dev/sda1 in my case and Instance Image Device /dev/nvme0n1p1.
Before this, when the name wa the same I'm resizing partition without problem.
By now I just reboot the Ec2 but I'm looking for another best solution

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Linux (and some other AMIs) are configured to automatically expand the root partition on startup.

Therefore, the steps to expand the volume space are:

- **Modify** the EBS Volume to add additional storage
- **Reboot** the instance
- **Confirm** that the space has increased